# Child dropdown not centering under parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation bar at the top of my page, and the dropdown menus are not centering under their parents correctly. I've tried setting the left margin to zero, however that makes the dropdowns align to the left of the nav and not the left of the parent.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RedvWG

```css
    nav{

 float:right;
 display: inline-block;
 position: fixed;
 white-space: nowrap;
    }

    nav ul li{

 display: inline;
 padding-left: 5px;
 float: left;
    }

    nav ul ul{

 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 width: inherit;
    }

    nav ul{

 list-style-type: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 position: relative;
    }

    nav a{

 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 display: block;
    }

    nav ul li:hover > ul{

 display: inline-block;
    }

    nav ul ul li{

 float:none;
 display: list-item;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
    }

    nav ul ul li a{

 text-align: center;

    }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Genres</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the default padding on the `ul` was causing the unwanted behavior. I rearranged your CSS so it cascades better, too. You should keep your less specific selectors near the top, and get more specific as you go down the stylesheet.

https://codepen.io/tehpsalmist/pen/PyLVWK

```
nav {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0; /* This solved it */
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
  position: relative;
    float: left;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: block;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
    display: list-item;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you and have a blessed day.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set nested 'ul' lists padding to 0 and optionally overwrite 'li' in nested 'ul' elements padding-left to 0.

```
ul ul { padding: 0 }
ul ul li { padding-left: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav{

 float:right;
 display: inline-block;
 position: fixed;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

nav ul li{

 display: inline;
 padding-left: 5px;
 float: left;
  position:relative;
}

nav ul ul{

 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 width: inherit;
  padding:0;
  left:-5px;
  
}

nav ul{

 list-style-type: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 position: relative;
}

nav a{

 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 display: block;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul{

 display: inline-block;

  
}

nav ul ul li{

 float:none;
 display: list-item;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav ul ul li a{

 text-align: center;

}
```

```html
  <nav>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Genres</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I also have another dropdown like this, and using a negative left element moves the second dropdown as well as the first, which I don't want.

Comment: See my updated comment i've added a snippet i should've mentioned you need relative positioning on the original `li` so it offsets the negative `left` relative to the `li` and not the `body`